# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, sentiment-analysis, valueerror

[image]I am working with **sentiment analysis** about **product review** and applying it with **cnn** by  **python** and i got this **ValueEror**. my dataset is in bangla language and the experimental dataset contain 1000 value.how could i get rid of this value error.
the **ValueError** is :
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 448 but received input with shape (None, 14944)

Comment: Try adding more context to your question by providing [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), dataset info, etc. for people to actually find out the issue.

Comment: i add a snippet of my code now

Comment: Error looks like, Input value that your Model is getting is different from actual input shape. Reshape the input value or change the input shape.Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)